# Visual c# form1 does not contain a definition for width

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to resize a form window and all the MSDN pages I've found tell me to just use form.width or form.height etc. But Visual studio doesn't show that as an option in the IntelliSense popups.

It does popup if I use this.width but what if I want to click a button in form1 to resize form2? How do change the properties by form name?

What am I missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.Width = 800; //ERROR: does not contain a definition for width
            this.Width = 800; //this is allowed though
            Form2.Width = 800; //ERROR: does not contain a definition for width

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //thought mayeb I need a size 1st so tried this
            Form1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size.(1029, 640); //ERROR:  An object reference is required for ... 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Size.get'    

            //dunno why this doesnt work its apparently correct acording to MSDN
            //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984427(v=vs.71).aspx
            //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229606(v=vs.110).aspx
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't done any Visual studio UI stuff since I played with VB6  a looooong time ago and I'm sure it used to be possible to just access any form by name and manipulate it.

Update: I changed `width` to `Width` based on comments and the problem still persists, so case sensitivity doesn't seem to be the problem.

Update: I see what's going on now. So what I really need to know is how do I reference the instance of form1 that has already been executed at startup from within a separate form?

So I instantiate form2 and show it. Now if I want to have a button on form2 to manipulate form1, how do I reference it when I never instantiated it into a variable? (since form1 is run automatically when the program starts)

Comment: this is because you need to create an Instance of `Form1` in order to get at the Width property for example `var frmForm1 = new Form1();` then `frmForm1.Width` is accessable other wise `this.Width` is proper. I would suggest reading up on the key word `this` as well as creating `Instance of Objects`

Comment: @MethodMan  Ahh okay. But wont that create and additional copy of form1 thats already being displayed at run time? I tried adding this to the end and I get a memmory exception fault..

//another test...
            var frm = new Form1();
            frm.Width = 800;
            frm.ShowDialog();

Comment: I think that you need to read up more as well as understand what happens when you create an instance of an Object. using the code that I have put in the answer will work correctly without any additional memory in regards to your concerns about memory exceptions read up on the Dispose method to understand whats going on there as well.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

try the following and you will see that it will work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Width = 800; //this is in reference to Form1
    var frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Width = 800;
    frm2.ShowDialog(); 
    frm2.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is case sensitve; `width` should be `Width`. Also, as shown in a latter error that you've included in the code comments, those (Form1 and likely Form2) are `class` identifiers, not instances. You can only reference the `static`elements of a class through the class name.

Answer (score 0):

As Uueerdo said, `width` should be `Width`. Also, (again as he says) `Form1` and `Form2` are classes names, you cannot use those to affect the values of your forms in C#. Instead you will want to affect those values on the current instance, which is represented by `this` in C#

`this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size.(1029, 640)`

If I recall correctly, in VB you can modify the forms through their class names like you are doing, but it's not the case in C#